Set the SMS priority in code (between transactional and promotional)
I use AWS SNS to send One-Time Passcodes to users with this code:
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});
const sns = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31', profile_name: "sms"});

var params = {
  PhoneNumber: phone,
  Message: message
}

var publish_text_promise = sns.publish(params).promise();

The account-level settings for the SMS delivery is transactional, so the wait for the passcode is at a minimum:

Sometimes, I also want to send them reminders, e.g. "You haven't used the website in 3 months, so your data will be deleted." These can be transactional, which are cheaper. I cannot find a way to change this setting with the Boto3 SDK, neither can I create a new topic and subscription with this setting (it's at the account level, not the topic level).
How can I send SMS messages with different settings, transactional or promotional, on my client code?
